# add new columns in pandas depending on other columns values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hello I would need help in order to add two new columns in a dataframe such as:

```
Name           start1  end1
OK0100087.1_0  0      375
OK0100087.1_1  376    750
OK0100087.1_2  751    1000
OK0100088.1    0      87766  
OK0100089.1    0      66778
OK0100090.1_0  0      47519
OK0100090.1_1  47520  73733
```

and the idea would be to add `start2` and `end2` such as:

```
Name           start1 end1  start2 end2 
OK0100087.1_0  0      375   1000   625 
OK0100087.1_1  376    750   624    250
OK0100087.1_2  751    1000  249    0
OK0100088.1    0      87766 87766  0      
OK0100089.1    0      66778 66778  0
OK0100090.1_0  0      47519 73733  26214
OK0100090.1_1  47520  73733 26213  0
```

so the idea in order to find the `start2` and `end2` new values is to within each `Name` **content_number**

so for instance `OK0100087.1`:

```
Name           start1 end1  start2 end2 
OK0100087.1_0  0      375    
OK0100087.1_1  376    750   
OK0100087.1_2  751    1000
```

take the **highest value = 1000**

then the first `start2` will be **1000.**

```
Name           start1 end1  start2 end2 
OK0100087.1_0  0      375   1000   
OK0100087.1_1  376    750   
OK0100087.1_2  751    1000
```

then the first `end2` will be = **start2-(end1-start1)** so **1000 - (375-0) = 625**

```
Name           start1 end1  start2 end2 
OK0100087.1_0  0      375   1000   625 
OK0100087.1_1  376    750   
OK0100087.1_2  751    1000
```

then second `start2` will be **end2-1 (625-1) = 624**

```
Name           start1 end1  start2 end2 
OK0100087.1_0  0      375   1000   625 
OK0100087.1_1  376    750   624
```

then again `end2` will be **start2-(end1-start1)** so **624 - (750-376) = 250**

```
Name           start1 end1  start2 end2 
OK0100087.1_0  0      375   1000   625 
OK0100087.1_1  376    750   624    250
```

etc

at the end we should get :

```
Name           start1 end1  start2 end2 
OK0100087.1_0  0      375   1000   625 
OK0100087.1_1  376    750   624    250
OK0100087.1_2  751    1000  249    0
OK0100088.1    0      87766 87766  0      
OK0100089.1    0      66778 66778  0
OK0100090.1_0  0      47519 73733  26214
OK0100090.1_1  47520  73733 26213  0
```

does someone have and idea in order to do that ? thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just `groupby().transform()`, given you can extract the unique name:

```
total = df.groupby(df.Name.str.extract('^([^\.]+)')[0])['end1'].transform('max')

df['start2'] = total - df['start1']

df['end2'] = total - df['end1']
```

Output:

```
            Name  start1   end1  start2   end2
0  OK0100087.1_0       0    375    1000    625
1  OK0100087.1_1     376    750     624    250
2  OK0100087.1_2     751   1000     249      0
3    OK0100088.1       0  87766   87766      0
4    OK0100089.1       0  66778   66778      0
5  OK0100090.1_0       0  47519   73733  26214
6  OK0100090.1_1   47520  73733   26213      0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['OK0100087.1_0',
  'OK0100087.1_1',
  'OK0100087.1_2',
  'OK0100088.1',
  'OK0100089.1',
  'OK0100090.1_0',
  'OK0100090.1_1'],
 'start1': [0, 376, 751, 0, 0, 0, 47520],
 'end1': [375, 750, 1000, 87766, 66778, 47519, 73733]})


df['base'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[0])
df['start2'] = df.groupby('base')['end1'].transform('max')

output = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)
for index, group in df.groupby('base'):
    t = group.copy()
    for x in range(len(group)):
        
        t['end2'] = t['start2'] - (t['end1'] - t['start1'])
        t['start2'].update((t['end2'] - 1).shift(1))
    output = output.append(t)
    
    
output.drop(columns='base', inplace=True)

output['end2'] = output['end2'].astype(int)
```

Output

```
             Name   start1  end1    start2    end2
0   OK0100087.1_0        0  375       1000     625
1   OK0100087.1_1      376  750        624     250
2   OK0100087.1_2      751  1000       249       0
3   OK0100088.1          0  87766    87766       0
4   OK0100089.1          0  66778    66778       0
5   OK0100090.1_0        0  47519    73733   26214
6   OK0100090.1_1    47520  73733    26213       0
```